# Get file commit time in GitPython

Tags: python-3.x, gitpython

How we can get the commit time of file (blob) via `Gitpython` while traversing the tree?

I need to get commit time of each **FILE (not directory)** in the full repo/tree. Something as we get via command `git log -1 --pretty="format:%cI" <file_path>`

```
repo = git.Repo('some_repo')
tree = repo.tree().traverse()
for blob in tree:
    print(blob.path)
    if os.path.isfile(blob.abspath):
       # get commit_time of blob something like 'git log -1 --pretty="format:%cI" blob.path'

       # this works but create mess with environment
       # os.popen(f'git log -1 --pretty="format:%cI" {str(blob.path)}').read()
```

I tried by traversing the full directory with `pathlib.Path` then passing the git directory by command `git -C <path_to_git_dir> log -1 --pretty="format:%cI" <file_path>`, but it created mess as this code has to be run within another git repository , hence preferred using `gitPython` not via git from environment.